# Could not find the optimal solution after adding constraints

Tags: constraints, solver, gekko

My code is as follows:

```py
gekko = GEKKO(remote=True)
# create variable, each variable is a vector, each element
#   of the vector is a binary
s = []
for i in range(N):
    s.append(gekko.Array(gekko.Var, s_len[i], value=0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True))
# some constants used in the objective/constraint function
c, d, r, m, L = create_c_d_r_m_L() # they are all numpy ndarry
 
# define the objective function
def objective():
    obj = 0
    for i in range(N):
        obj += np.dot(s[i], c[i]) + np.dot(s[i], d[i])
    for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(E):
        obj += np.dot(np.dot(s[i], r[idx].reshape(s_len[i], s_len[j])),\
                      s[j]) # s[i] * r[i, j] * s[j]
    return obj

# add constraints
# (a) each vector can only have and must have one 1
for i in range(N):
    gekko.Equation(gekko.sum(s[i]) == 1)
# (b) 
for t in range(N):
    peak_mem = gekko.sum([np.dot(s[i], m[i]) for i in L[t]])
    gekko.Equation(peak_mem < DEVICE_MEM) 
# DEVICE_MEM is a predefined big int

# solve
gekko.Obj(objective())
gekko.solve(disp=True)
```

I found that when removing constraint (`b`), the solver can output the optimal solution for s. However, if we add (`b`) and set `DEVICE_MEM` to a very large number (which should not affect the solution), the `s` is not optimal anymore. I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong here because I tried both APOPT(solvertype=1) and IPOPT (solvertype=3) and they give the same nonoptimal results.

To give more context to the problem: this is an optimization over the graph. `N` represents the number of nodes in the graph. `E` is the set that contains all edges in the graph. `c`, `d`, `m` are three types of cost of a node. `r` is the cost of edges. Each node has multiple strategies (represented by the vector `s[i]`), and we need to select the best strategy for each node so that the overall cost is minimal.

Detailed constants:

```py
# s_len: record the length of each vector
#   (the # of strategies for each node, 
#    here we assume the length are all 10)
s_len = np.ones(N) * 10

# c, d, m are the costs of each node
# let's assume the c/d/m cost for i node is just i
c, d, m = [], [], []
for i in range(N):
    c[i] = s_len[i] * [i]
    d[i] = s_len[i] * [i]
    m[i] = s_len[i] * [i]

# r is the edge cost, let's assume the cost for
#    each edge is just i * j
r = []
for (i,j) in E: # E records all edges
   cur_r = s_len[i] * s_len[j] * [i*j]
   r.append(cur_r)

# L contains the node ids, we just randomly generate 10 integers here
L = []
for i in range(N):
    cur_L = [randrange(N) for _ in range(10)]
    L.append(cur_L)
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and any comments/answers are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try reframing the inequality constraint:

```py
for t in range(N):
    peak_mem = gekko.sum([np.dot(s[i], m[i]) for i in L[t]])
    gekko.Equation(peak_mem < DEVICE_MEM)
```

as a variable with an upper bound:

```py
peak_mem = m.Array(m.Var,N,ub=DEVICE_MEM)
for t in range(N):
    m.Equation(peak_mem[t]==\
               gekko.sum([np.dot(s[i], m[i]) for i in L[t]])
```

The `N` inequality constraints `peak_mem < DEVICE_MEM` are converted to equality constraints with slack variables as `s[i] = DEVICE_MEM - peak_mem` with a simple inequality constraint on the slack `s[i]>=0`. If the inequality constraint far from the bound, then the slack variable can be very large. Formulating the equation as a variable may help.

I tried using the information in the question to pose a minimal problem that could reproduce the error and the potential solution. If you need more specific suggestions, please modify the code to be a complete and minimal example that reproduces the error. This helps with verifying the solution.